# In SQL, How to output "NULL" instead of " There are no results to be displayed" when there's no value to be exported

Tags: mysql, database, isnull

Using MySQL v8.0 right now.

The question is:

> Write an SQL query to report the id and the salary of the second highest salary from the
> Employee table. If there is no second highest salary, the query should
> report null.

My dummy data is:

```
Create table If Not Exists Employee (id int, salary int);
insert into Employee (id, salary) values 
(1, 100);
```

My ideal output is like this:

```
+------+--------+
|  id  | salary |
+------+--------+
| NULL |  NULL  |
+------+--------+
```

I used DENSE_RANK as a more straightforward way for me to solve this question:

```
WITH sub AS (SELECT id,
       salary,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY salary DESC) AS num
       FROM Employee )
SELECT id, salary
FROM sub
WHERE num = 2
```

But I have a problem exporting NULL when there's no second highest salary. I tried IFNULL, but it didn't work. I guess it's because the output is not actually null but just empty.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: (edit) Yep, ifnull() only works if there's a record (or more) returned.  There may be a better option, but you could use UNION ALL to append the null values `select null, null`. Then order the results by `salary desc` so non-null values appear first, then add  `limit 1` to return a single record. That'll return the second highest salary if there is one. Otherwise, it will return `null, null`

Comment: if there is more than one id with the second highest salary, do you want more than one row returned?

Comment: @ysth If there are more than one ids with the same second highest salary, output them all. That's why I put `DENSE_RANK` and `num=2`. Sorry I didn't clarify it.

Comment: @SOS Can you be more specific about how to UNION ALL, and then order the unioned output in salary desc and limit 1?

Comment: @ericzheng0404 - I just posted a more detailed explanation as an answer with a fiddle example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
WITH sub AS (
    SELECT id,
           salary,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY salary DESC) AS num
    FROM Employee 
)
SELECT id, salary
FROM sub
WHERE num = 2
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL
WHERE 0 = ( SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM sub 
            WHERE num = 2 );
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=31f5afb0e7e5dce9c2c128ccc49a6f42

Comment: That's exactly what I want. Thank you, sir!

Answer (score 0):

Just making your query a subquery and left joining from a single-row producing subquery seems to me the simplest approach:

```
select id, salary
from (select null) at_least_one_row
left join (
    select id, salary
    from (
        select id, salary, dense_rank() over (order by salary desc) as num
        from Employee
    ) ranked_employees
    where num = 2
) second_highest_salary on true
```

(I usually prefer a subquery to a cte that's only used once; I find that obfuscatory.)

Comment: Great answer. `SELECT NULL` is a totally different approach than my thinking. Thank you!

Comment: the value isn't used, it might as well be select 1 or select 'foo'